# "Anagram" program written in C

Tags: c, anagram

Full disclosure I am a college student working on a homework assignment. I am not necessarily looking for a direct answer to my question but more a nudge in the right direction. So here is my problem. I have to write a C program that takes in 2 command line arguments, one is a file containing a list of words and the other is a single word. Now the reason I have the word anagram in quotation marks is because it's not *really* an anagram.

Here are the problem requirements:
I need to take the word from the command line (dog) and compare it to the dictionary list (doggie). If the letters in the command line word exist then I need to output a message like `You can't spell "doggie" without "dog"!` So I am simply checking if the letters from the command line argument exist in the words in the dictionary file.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 80

int anagram(char a[], char b[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <list> <goal>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    } else {
        char cmdLn[MAX_WORD_LENGTH], comp[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
        strcpy(cmdLn, argv[2]);
        while (fgets(comp, sizeof comp, file) != NULL) {
            strtok(comp, "\n");
            int flag = anagram(cmdLn, comp);
            if (flag == 1) {
                printf("You can't spell \"%s\" without \"%s\".\n", cmdLn, comp);
            } else {
                printf("There's no \"%s\" in \"%s\".\n", cmdLn, comp);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}

int anagram(char a[], char b[]) {

    return 1;
}
```

So I need to figure out an algorithm to compare each character of the command line word with each character of the word in the dictionary file. If I find each letter I from the `anagram` function I return 1 if I don't I return 0. I simply can't figure out how to approach this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I can assume all letters are lower case in both the dictionary file and the command line. Also each word can be no longer than 80 characters and there will be no numbers in the words.

Comment: Can you clarify what should be the result if the word is `good` and the dictionary includes `doggie`?

Comment: Your description sounds like you are looking for substring matching logic. Is it so?

Comment: One way to deal with it is to convert words in the dictionary into a sorted list of 'letter, count', so `doggie` maps to "d1e1g2i1o1".  You can then map your sample word (`dog` or `good`) too: `"d1g1o1"` or `"d1g1o2"` .  Then you can compare the signatures; if a letter required by the sample word is missing, or the count isn't big enough, then the comparison fails.  You may or may not decide to worry about a single letter being repeated more than 9 times.  However, even 'antidisestablishmentarianism' or 'floccinaucinihilipilification' don't break that (but the latter has 9 `i`'s in it).

Comment: Step 1 is to precisely define your requirements, which means answering the questions posed by @ Wimmel and @ Jay. Because you haven't fully specified the problem, the answers you've received are just guesses, that may be totally wrong.

Comment: [Déjà-vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572653/check-if-all-char-values-are-present-in-string)

Comment: `strtok(comp, "\n");` is not the recommended way to strip the trailing newline. Prefer `comp[strcspn(comp, "\n")] = '\0';` that does not have side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical, higher level language approach would be to use a set or hash of the letters.  But let's keep it simple:

> Make a copy of the command line word.
>
> Loop through the letters in the file word:
>       Loop through the letters in the copy word:
>           If a letter from each matches, strike out that letter in the copy word (e.g. change it to *)
>
> After the loops, if all the letters of the copy word are gone (i.e.
>   stars), it's a match

```
int anagram(char *a, char *b) {

    size_t counter = 0, a_len = strlen(a), b_len = strlen(b);

    char *c = strdup(a);

    for (int j = 0; j < b_len; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a_len; i++) {
            if (c[i] == b[j]) {
                c[i] = '*';
                counter++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    free(c);

    return (counter == a_len);
}
```

You'll need to fix the above to ignore case.

Comment: I think this answer is closest to what I want. But I do have a few questions, when I try this code I get an error "implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’" but I have already included <string.h> My compiler flags are c11 -Wall con.c, I am not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: So this works! I would still like to figure out my compiler errors though. I really want to understand what is happening here.

Comment: @Albright, if `char *c = strdup(a)` is an issue, you can substitute `char *c = strcpy(malloc(a_len + 1), a)`, or something like that.  On my system `string.h` declares `strdup()`

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Read a word from file
Use an `int` as a flag - set it to 1 (meaning all letters in test word are present in word from file)
Loop through the test word taking one letter at a time - remember a string can be accessed as an array of characters.

Use strchr to test if the letter appears in the word read from file.
If it does not appear (look at what strchr returns for not found), change the flag to 0 and break out of the comparison loop

Print a message depending on the flag value - if flag is still 1 then all letters were present, else at least one letter was not present.

```
    /* set flag to 'letters all present' */
    int flag = 1;
    /* test word from file for each letter in test word */
    for (n = 0; n < strlen(word);  n++) {
        if(strchr(line, word[n]) == NULL) {
            /* set flag to letter not present */
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since this only checks letter existence, but not count, wouldn't it lead to mismatches like, "You can't spell "doggie" without "doog"!

Comment: @cdlane I didn't read that into the question. Perhaps you need to ask the OP if that was the intention. I just saw `So I am simply checking if the letters from the command line argument exist in the words in the dictionary file.`